# What is a good beginner's online resource for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reference

I have 3 days to learn the basics of ASP.NET MVC and create a very small PoC web application with it.

What are currently the best online resources for:

1. Learning the basics in a tutorial-like way
2. Reference material regarding ASP.NET MVC
3. Best practices regarding the use of ASP.NET MVC

I am not looking for general info about the MVC pattern since I have been using it in past (desktop) applications.

#### Please note:

This question has been asked before on SO, but the big threads I have seen are about half a year old already and seeing the pace at which ASP.NET evolves I am not sure if those are still up to date and if there aren't better choices by now.

Comment: Start with MVC 4/Beta tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4 Shoot me an email and I'll send you Music Store in MVC 4/Beta

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best source for almost all of you ASP.NET MVC framework questions (including tutorials in text and video format) is going to come from the official source as http://www.asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 14):

For ASP.net MVC 4, Microsoft has released a getting started guide:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

For ASP.net MVC 1, There is also a free eBook released by Scott Hanselman, Phil Haack, Scott Guthrie and Rob Conery. This is rather outdated by now, but may still be of interest to some:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/03/10/free-asp-net-mvc-ebook-tutorial.aspx

That's more of a concrete project walkthrough rather than a standard tutorial though.

Comment: I was just coming to suggest that.  Things didn't 'click' for me until I read it.

Comment: That's ancient. Better to use the lastest version of MVC (4 Beta) http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: @Rick.Anderson-at-Microsoft.com You do realise that most of the answers you are criticising/downvoting here as “out of date” are three years old? Of *course* they're out of date... as are most of the answers on StackOverflow, if you look at it that way — it doesn't mean that they weren't helpful at the time. Why not add an answer with what you think are the best resources?

Comment: @mark: One of the important features of SO is that answers stay up to date. While the whole "Wiki/Edit" stuff never really worked, it is IMHO still important to declare old answers as outdated with a link to a new resource. This question still gets traffic, but if Rick posts an answer (he should) it may take a long time to get 11 Votes (to be more than mine), if ever. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Mark, I didn't realize that and I corrected my error. If you don't want Beta, follow http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs

Answer (score 5):

I would start with [ASP.NET MVC How-Do-I.](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/) The ASP.NET MVC Storefront Starter Kit and the ASP.NET MVC Pair Programming are all really good for step by step learning.

Comment: 3 second differential, that's a new personal record for closeness to another post for me.

Comment: TheTXI: all right, you also get a plus point for me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one great video from [Scott Allen](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/) in pluralsight. This is free

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-intro&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro

Answer (score 0):

[Stephan Walther's blog](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/Default.aspx) is another good source of links and info (most resolving to those suggested here).

Comment: Bad link and all Walther's MVC blogs are out of date. Use http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

Answer (score 0):

I just found your question - I've been searching too and found this site, which I thought was a good, plain english guide:

http://www.howmvcworks.net/

Answer (score -1):

[Scott Gu's](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/) and [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/) provides you some straightforward "tips". It's true that older posts uses out dated MVC version, but the majority of the content is still valid. The basics (how and *why*) you need can be found there.

Answer (score -1):

These links could be useful:

[Asp.net and C#: MVC](http://asp-net-csharp-vb.blogspot.com/search/label/MVC%20%28Model%20View%20Controller%29)

[Asp.net and C#: Introducing MVC Development w/the Razor View Engine for Visual Studio Developers](http://asp-net-csharp-vb.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-mvc-development-wthe-razor.html)

Comment: Those links are not good for getting started. Why would you start with routing?